# Is OpenId Connect response_type id_token supported by WSO2 Identity Server 5.0

Tags: wso2, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to implement OpenId Connect in an SPA application with WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0. I'm trying to use Implicit Flow but I always received an error from the identity server.

GET Request:

```
https://idserver:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&
    client_id=abcd&
    redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44326%2F
```

Error Response:

```
invalid_request, Invalid response_type parameter value
```

Is response_type=id_token supported?

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this problem? We encountered the same issue and wondering if there's workaround for this or we need to switch to a different STS.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I thought WSO2 fully supported OpenIDConnect.

Answer (score 2):

With WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 OpenID Connect "id_token" response type is not implemented.  The "Implicit" settings in the configuration only work for OAuth 2.0 "token" response type. You might wait until 5.1.0 or take the pain of implementing a patch for it.

Comment: We're still using 5.0.0  If I can't use "id_token", then is there a way that i could use "token" response type first (just using it as 'implicit' OAuth2 grant type), and acquire the JWT id_token in another call ?