# WSO2 Identity Server OpenId Connect Owin

Tags: wso2, owin, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

Im trying to set up WSO2 Identity Server to use OpenId connect. I have currently applied the following settings shown [Here: Setup WSO2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEQmi.jpg).

What it boiles down to is that i use the Resident Identity Provider and i have setup a Service Provider for my app "CoolApp".

I configured "OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration" and set a callback URL.

Is there a simple example how to use this in javascript?

I have played around with identityserver3 and they have a client oidc-client.js which works nicely in combination with identityserver3. However i cant seem to get it working with WSO2 identity server.

---

I was going about the issue in a wrong way, what i actually wanted was to protect my website using the owin middleware like they tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058960/owin-openid-connect-authorization-fails-to-authorize-secured-controller-action?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773419/wso2-identity-server-with-openid-connect).

so now i have the following:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("ClientCookie");

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AuthenticationType = "ClientCookie",
            CookieName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + "ClientCookie",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
        });

        // ***************************************************************************
        // Approach 1 : ResponseType = "id_token token"
        // ***************************************************************************
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AuthenticationType = OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = app.GetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(),
            Authority = "   https://localhost:9443/oauth2/",
            ClientId = "fgx4M5e27NJqgRIs8nu5aL7Jw3oa",
            ClientSecret = "dwGdRDCFY7Soa7CB5K5smkiuMmYa",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:57815/Account/ExternalLoginCallback/",
            ResponseType = "id_token token",
            Scope = "openid",

            Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
            {
                AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize",
                TokenEndpoint = "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token",
                UserInfoEndpoint = "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo",
            },

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                {
                    var token = n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken;

                    // persist access token in cookie
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                    {
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(
                            new Claim("access_token", token));
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },

                AuthenticationFailed = notification =>
                {

                    if (string.Equals(notification.ProtocolMessage.Error, "access_denied", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        notification.HandleResponse();

                        notification.Response.Redirect("/");
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                }
            }
        });
```

I put a break point in the SecurityTokenValidated and AuthenticationFailed. Go to the page and i get redirected to the WSO2 identity server as expected. When i login and return to the page both of my break points are NOT hit and im not logged in.

Im using WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0.

@farasath, could you please help me and the others out looks like we are all running into the same issue and havent found a solution yet.

During further investigation i found out that using the code flow with response_type = "code" will not work either, as the OIDC middleware doesn't support it (see [here](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/247) and [here](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/manfredsteyer/OIDCResponseModeQuery/contribution/7009)).

Found a suggestion by @pinpoint that ASP.net core does support this. But this is not really an option.

@Hos answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120850/is-openid-connect-response-type-id-token-supported-by-wso2-identity-server-5-0/29140396#29140396):

> With WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 OpenID Connect "id_token" response type is not implemented.

Im not getting the error response he mentioned in his post, but the results for me stay the same using these versions, the breakpoints never get hit. So now i'm wondering should this actually work in 5.1.0 or in the 5.2.0-Beta or is this still WIP.

---

@farasath, Thank you for your reply here are the logs

```
[2016-08-16 08:11:39,998] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Validate Client information request for client_id : fgx4M5e27NJqgRIs8nu5aL7Jw3oa and callback_uri http://localhost:57815/
[2016-08-16 08:11:40,074] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Registered App found for the given Client Id : fgx4M5e27NJqgRIs8nu5aL7Jw3oa ,App Name : CoolApp, Callback URL : http://localhost:57815/
[2016-08-16 08:11:50,948] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Authorization Request received for user : raymond@carbon.super, Client ID : fgx4M5e27NJqgRIs8nu5aL7Jw3oa, Authorization Response Type : id_token token, Requested callback URI : http://localhost:57815/, Requested Scope : openid
[2016-08-16 08:11:50,967]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.config.OAuthServerConfiguration} -  The default OAuth token issuer will be used. No custom token generator is set.
[2016-08-16 08:11:50,985]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO} -  Thread pool size for session persistent consumer : 100
[2016-08-16 08:11:50,991] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenPersistenceTask} -  Access Token context persist consumer is started
... This one repeats about 100 times ...
[2016-08-16 08:11:51,031] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.authz.AuthorizationHandlerManager} -  Successfully created AppInfoCache under OAuthCacheManager
[2016-08-16 08:11:51,206] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Added OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext to threadlocal
[2016-08-16 08:11:52,180] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.authz.handlers.TokenResponseTypeHandler} -  No active access token found in cache for Client ID : fgx4M5e27NJqgRIs8nu5aL7Jw3oa, User ID : raymond@carbon.super and Scope : openid
[2016-08-16 08:11:52,199] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.authz.handlers.TokenResponseTypeHandler} -  No access token found in database for Client ID : fgx4M5e27NJqgRIs8nu5aL7Jw3oa, User ID : raymond@carbon.super and Scope : openid. Therefore issuing new access token
[2016-08-16 08:11:52,208] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenPersistenceTask} -  Access Token Data persisting Task is started to run
[2016-08-16 08:11:52,208] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.authz.handlers.TokenResponseTypeHandler} -  Persisted Access Token for Client ID : fgx4M5e27NJqgRIs8nu5aL7Jw3oa, Authorized User : raymond@carbon.super, Timestamp : 2016-08-16 08:11:52.207, Validity period (s) : 3600, Scope : openid, Callback URL : http://localhost:57815/, Token State : ACTIVE and User Type : APPLICATION_USER
[2016-08-16 08:11:52,233] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.authz.handlers.TokenResponseTypeHandler} -  Access Token was added to OAuthCache for cache key : fgx4M5e27NJqgRIs8nu5aL7Jw3oa:raymond@carbon.super:openid
[2016-08-16 08:11:52,298] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Cleared OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext
```

Second time i ran it i got this log:

```
[2016-08-16 08:30:17,216] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Validate Client information request for client_id : fgx4M5e27NJqgRIs8nu5aL7Jw3oa and callback_uri http://localhost:57815/
[2016-08-16 08:30:17,222] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Registered App found for the given Client Id : fgx4M5e27NJqgRIs8nu5aL7Jw3oa ,App Name : CoolApp, Callback URL : http://localhost:57815/
[2016-08-16 08:30:23,178] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} -  Authorization Request received for user : raymond@carbon.super, Client ID : fgx4M5e27NJqgRIs8nu5aL7Jw3oa, Authorization Response Type : id_token token, Requested callback URI : http://localhost:57815/, Requested Scope : openid
[2016-08-16 08:30:23,189] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Added OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext to threadlocal
[2016-08-16 08:30:23,195] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.authz.handlers.TokenResponseTypeHandler} -  Retrieved active Access Token for Client Id : fgx4M5e27NJqgRIs8nu5aL7Jw3oa, User ID :raymond@carbon.super and Scope : openid from cache
[2016-08-16 08:30:23,203] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.authz.handlers.TokenResponseTypeHandler} -  Access Token is valid for another 3264638ms
[2016-08-16 08:30:23,218] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util} -  Cleared OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext
```

---

Now i changed my redirect uri to:
    RedirectUri = "http://localhost:57815/Account/ExternalLoginCallback/",

and logInfo in that function is always null
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

Googled around and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773419/wso2-identity-server-with-openid-connect) where someone was having similar problems.

---

Used Fiddler to look at the callback looks like a cookie has been set [image: Screenshot]

---

So now Im left with the following situation:

- Breakpoint in SecurityTokenValidated never hit
- Breakpoint in AuthenticationFailed never hit
- var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(); is always null in my Callback

Comment: @farasath i had to edit my question in stead of using an answer like i did (this was pointed out to me by a reviewer). So unfortunately your comments got lost too. But like you requested i ran with logging turned on and i also did some further investigation with fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this is OWIN middle-ware is expecting the OAUTH response in OAUTH 2.0 Form Post Response Mode [1] which is an optional spec and only Identity Server 5.2.0 (With a patch) upwards supports this.

[1] http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK we don't have a Javascript sample that you can use directly. But that shouldn't be a problem at all. I came across [1] by simply googling. All you need to do is to replace the client_id and callback URL. Since we follow the OAuth/OpenID connect spec any OAuth Javascript client library should work with WSO2 Identity Server.

We do have a web app sample[2] and I wrote a blog post[3] earlier just to demonstrate the authorization code flow with WSO2 Identity Server.

[1] https://github.com/zalando/oauth2-client-js

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/OAuth+2.0+with+WSO2+Playground

[3] http://blog.farazath.com/2016/05/trying-out-oauth2-authorization-code.html

Comment: i tried to rephrase the question because i realized i started off wrong.